# Replace dot(.) with comma(,) using RegEx?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, cultureinfo, decimal-point

I am working on a C# application. I want to change number decimal figure with comma(,) where i have dot(.) using regular expression.

For example:

```
Price= 100,00.56
```

As  this international rule of representing numeric values but I Sweden they have different ways for numbers Like

```
Price= 100.00,56
```

So i want to change dot(.) into comma(,) and comma(,) into dot(.) using RegEx. Could guide me about this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When formatting numbers, you should use the [string format overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx) that takes a [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) object. The culture name for swedish is "sv-SE", as can be seen [here](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/globalization/demos/CultureInfo.aspx).

```
decimal value = -16325.62m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE")));
```

**Edit**:

As @OregonGhost points out - parsing out numbers should also be done with `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Virtual +1, sadly I'm out of votes today. But know you earned it. :)

Comment: +1 for the canonical solution. It's important to note though that this is not only the solution for *formatting*, but also for *parsing* numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Not a RegEx solution but from my experience - more correct:

```
public static string CheckDecimalDigitsDelimiter(this string instance)
{
    var sv = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
    var en = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    decimal d;
    return (!Decimal.TryParse(instance, NumberStyles.Currency, sv, out d) &&
            Decimal.TryParse(instance, NumberStyles.Currency, en, out d)) ?
        d.ToString(sv) : // didn't passed by SV but did by EN
        instance;
}
```

What does this method do? It ensures that if given string is incorrect Sweden string but is correct English - convert it to Sweden, e.g. `100,00 -> 100,00` but `100.00 -> 100,00`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this even without regex. For example

```
var temp = price.Replace(".", "<TEMP>");
var temp2 = temp.Replace(",", ".");
var replaced = temp2.Replace("<TEMP>", ",");
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what 100,00.56 represents, did you mean 10.000,56?

To answer your question:

For such a simple task, why use RegEx? You can do it much easier:

```
string oldValue = "100,00.56";
char dummyChar = '&'; //here put a char that you know won't appear in the strings
var newValue = oldValue.Replace('.', dummyChar)
                       .Replace(',', '.')
                       .Replace(dummyChar, ',');
```

**Edit**
I agree with @Oded, for formatting numbers use the `CultureInfo` class.

Comment: `100,00.56` is an English representation, `10.000,56` - Sweden/Russian/etc

Comment: @abati: I think he was talking about the fact that the OP's examples have only two digits between the thousands separator and the decimal separator.  It's probably just a typo.

Comment: fixed dummyChar  to be a variable not a literal in the last line.

Answer (score 5):

Also have a look at

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not rely on RegExp for this kind of thing :) Use the build in cultures fx:

```
decimal s = decimal.Parse("10,000.56", NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
string output = s.ToString("N",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK"));
```

en-US will parse it correctly and da-DK uses the other kind of representation. I live in DK and therefore use that but you should use the culture which fits your output.